# Dual screen won't work / Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, ubuntu-10.04, amd-radeon

I have an old computer, on which I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.  It has a graphical chipset built in the motherboard (Intel) but has some PCI slots.

I added an ATI Radeon 9200 graphical card in order to use dual screens, but I can't manage to make it work. The only thing I achieved was to remove `--purge xorg` and install it back. I tried a few things and finally broke X.

I don't even know where to start from.

Usually, when I turn the machine on, it will only use the primary monitor, but when I installed PPA drivers, I couldn't start X any more.

After the reboot, X won't start. However, curiously I had the Ubuntu logo on the second monitor (I have never seen a picture on this one before) then it turned black again and some glitches appeared on the primary screen. I couldn't log in, nor display a TTY.

Does anyone know a little more about the newer xorg configuration with old material?

I'm using X.Org X Server 1.8.2.

Driver installation logs:

```
Uninstalling any previously installed drivers.  
Unloading radeon module...  
Unloading drm module...  
ERROR: Module drm is in use by ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper  
[Message] Kernel Module : Trying to install a precompiled kernel module.  
[Message] Kernel Module : Precompiled kernel module version mismatched.  
[Message] Kernel Module : Found kernel module build environment, generating kernel module now.  
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1  
doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher  
rm -rf *.c *.h *.o *.ko *.a .??* *.symvers  
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-41-generic/build SUBDIRS=/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x modules  
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-41-generic'  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.o  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.o  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_agp.o  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_debug.o  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_ioctl.o  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_io.o  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_pci.o  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_str.o  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_iommu.o  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl.o  
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_wait.o  
  LD [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/fglrx.o  
  Building modules, stage 2.  
  MODPOST 1 modules  
  CC      /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/fglrx.mod.o  
  LD [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/fglrx.ko  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-41-generic'  
build succeeded with return value 0  
duplicating results into driver repository...  
done.  
You must change your working directory to /lib/modules/fglrx
and then call ./make_install.sh in order to install the built module.  
- recreating module dependency list  
- trying a sample load of the kernel modules  
failed.  
[Error] Kernel Module : Reboot required.   
[Reboot] Kernel Module : update-initramfs
```

**EDIT:**

```
root@pc-desktop:/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d# lspci | grep VGA  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)  
03:0c.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV280 [Radeon 9200 SE] (rev 01)
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
root@pc-desktop:/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d# sudo lshw -C video  
  *-display                 
       description: Display controller  
       product: 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller  
       vendor: Intel Corporation  
       physical id: 2  
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0  
       version: 02  
       width: 32 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom  
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0  
       resources: irq:16 memory:e0000000-e7ffffff(prefetchable) memory:d8000000-d807ffff   ioport:1800(size=8)  
  *-display:0  
       description: VGA compatible controller  
       product: RV280 [Radeon 9200 SE]  
       vendor: ATI Technologies Inc  
       physical id: c  
       bus info: pci@0000:03:0c.0  
       version: 01  
       width: 32 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom  
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=66 mingnt=8  
       resources: irq:20 memory:f0000000-f7ffffff(prefetchable) ioport:2400(size=256)   memory:d8110000-d811ffff memory:d8140000-d815ffff(prefetchable)  
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED  
       description: Display controller  
       product: RV280 [Radeon 9200 SE] (Secondary)  
       vendor: ATI Technologies Inc  
       physical id: c.1  
       bus info: pci@0000:03:0c.1  
       version: 01  
       width: 32 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list  
       configuration: latency=66 mingnt=8  
       resources: memory:e8000000-efffffff(prefetchable) memory:d8100000-d810ffff
```

Comment: Actually I'm working on the screen that is wired to the 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.
I did boot into recovery mode, root shell with networking.
I removed xorg, reinstalled it.
Then I did
X -configure
I copied the /root/xorg.conf.new file to /etc/X11/xorg.conf
I did check the parameter, it seemed allright.
I reboot, and pictures shows on both screens.

Answer (score 1):

- Download the driver from here -> http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx
- Uninstall the restricted drivers you installed using Synaptic.
- Extract and run the downloaded file using `sudo sh <filename goes here>`
- Install the software.
- Restart
- Run AMD Catalyst Center `gksudo amdcccle`
- Go to Display Manager
- There you should see your monitors.
- Click on the monitor you want to configure and chose display mode.
- Restart.

Comment: I have followed your instructions but after the first reboot, my main screen remains black.
I have the bios screen, then if I keep pressing Shift i can choose my kernel or recovery mode, but then it goes on "Power saving mode" and both remain black.
There is a fglrx-uninstall.sh script which is generated in the same folder as the install logs. I have uninstalled this and it works again.

Comment: When I first rebooted, the Ubuntu logo did show up on the 2nd screen so obviously the hardware works. (Then after the reboot when both screen went black, I started playing with the VGA connections. If I start the machine without screens, and wait for a while, then if I plug my main screen back in the motherboard built in VGA port, I am able to operate the machine back.) I edited the main post with the installation logs